# Load MySql Data From Database into TextBox in WPF with stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, stored-procedures, textbox

Thanks for Reading

I want to display Data from MySql Database into WPF Textbox using stored procedure in MySQL, I want to display information in the text boxes on the key up event, "vbid" is the stored procedure from MySQL and is given below, I am asking this because the number of Columns in the stored procedure is long and this is just an example I am temporarily solving, I know that there is method where you use SQL command in c#  and reference each using their index number
example :

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Name , Age etc... From exampletable where ID=@ID", con); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Mem_no", memno.Text.Trim());
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    textbox1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    textbox1.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    ........
                }
```

but I want a method which utilizes stored procedures is there any way to accomplish that, please do help, THANK YOU!

these are the two methods I tried to implement :

```
 private void memno_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connetionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            if (memno.Text != "") 
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("vbid", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Mem_no", memno.Text.Trim());
                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    // this is the only different part so I am writing this in different code fence 
                       so that the question isn't too long, I will name them method 1 and method 2 
                       as their title 
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    Method 1 :      memnm.Text = Request.QueryString["Mem_Name"];
                    fsn.Text = Request.QueryString["Father_Name"];
                    age.Text = Request.QueryString["Age"];
                    gndr.Text = Request.QueryString["Gender"];
                    dob.Text = Request.QueryString["Date_of_Birth"];
                    unm.Text = Request.QueryString["Union_name"];



Method 2 :          memnm.Text = dr["Mem_Name"].ToString();
                    fsn.Text = dr["Father_Name"].ToString();
                    age.Text = dr["Age"].ToString();
                    gndr.Text = dr["Gender"].ToString();
                    dob.Text = dr["Date_of_Birth"].ToString();
                    unm.Text = dr["Union_name"].ToString();
```

this is the Example Stored Procedure in MySql named "vbid"

```sql
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `vbid`()
 BEGIN
 SELECT   
 Mem_no,
 Mem_Name,
 Father_Name,
 Age,
 Gender,
 Date_of_Birth,
 Union_name
  
 FROM mi
  
 WHERE ID = _ID; 
 END
```

Thank You Again!!!

Comment: Your SP seems to be wrong - I doubt that both `ID` and `_ID` are columns in `mi` table.

Comment: ID is an unaltered autogenerated Index Column with unique Values and _ID is the Initializer in my c# code, and mi is obviously the table , but here instead of ID I am using Member number or memno as an index

Comment: *_ID is the Initializer in my c# code* MySQL knows nothing about entities which exists in c# code. If you want to use its value in a query you must transfer this value into SP as a parameter. And this parameter must be described in SP parameters list.

Comment: yes but I want the exact opposite to happen, C# doesn't know the entity in MySQL table, so is there any way for that to happen, there are values in MySQL table and I want c# to fetch the values according to the stored procedure, I apologize if I am making this confusing I am new to this field of development and thank you for baring with me

Comment: C# commands, MySQL executes. C# must tell to MySQL what it must do definitely. It can tell "give me a row where `ID` is 123" and receive the row if it exists, or it can tell `give me all rows`, receive all rows and search they for a value(s) it is interested in. MySQL - simply executes the order.

Comment: yes so what is the command for c# to tell MySQL to retrieve data in the text box , I want it to use the stored procedure that is already described and let MySQL give an output based on that procedure and make c# display that output in their respective textboxes

Comment: Your SP must have IN parameters. Like ```CREATE PROCEDURE `vbid`(IN _id INT, ...)```. You call it like a query with the parameters, like `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("vbid(@_id, ...)", con);` and profide the parameters values for execution like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_id", id_textbox.Text.Trim());`...

Answer (score 0):

it's fine, I figured it out, But thank you for even helping me
this was what I was searching for

```
private void memno_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connetionstring))
        {
          con.Open();
          if (memno.Text != "") 
           {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ch.mi WHERE Mem_no =" + 
            int.Parse(memno.Text.Trim()), con);
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    memnm.Text = dr.GetString("Mem_Name"); <--- this was the command I 
                    fsn.Text = dr.GetString("Father_Name");     was searching for 
                    age.Text = dr.GetInt32("Age").ToString();  *(pheww sigh of relief) 
                    gndr.Text = dr.GetString("Gender");
                    dob.Text = dr.GetString("Date_of_Birth");
                    unm.Text = dr.GetString("Union_name");
                }
                else 
                {
                    clear();  <--- this is a declared clear function 
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Not Available");
                
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

now irritatingly enough I have a new problem, this command cant accept null value
I am really hating this one problem after another
but real thanks to this community